# SQL timeouts in ASP.NET after server migration

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server

We have several ASP.NET WebForm sites running on IIS. We switched hosting providers and migrated all of the sites and databases.
After the migration, we are getting timeouts in several places in several sites after 30 seconds. Some are LINQ queries, some are MS Reports, some stored procs.

The code and web.configs were copied directly, so there should be no difference except for the SQL and IIS versions and configurations.
We  went from SQL Server 2014 to SQL Server 2019 now running on Windows Server 2019.
IIS server is also on a 2019 server.

In SQL Server, 'Allow remote connections' is checked with a remote query timeout of 600 seconds.

I have added 'Connection Timeout=120' to the connection string in the web.config but it is still timing out after 30 seconds.

Here is an example of one of them coming from a report:

> An error has occurred during report processing.
> Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
> Execution Timeout Expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
> The wait operation timed out

Some of these sites are pretty old and using older methods for connecting to database. I have seen some posts about adding a timeout to the `SqlCommand` object, but most places we have do not use one. Some code is within a custom data layer and I don't have access to all of the source code to try adding the timeout value.

Any ideas of where this timeout may be coming from?

Any direction would be appreciated.

Comment: The query engine changed quite a lot from 2012 to 2019 therefore some queries that performed well before may not perform well now. There is no magic cure, you have to identify the queries which are running slowly and performance tune them as normal.

Comment: Linq will generate back end SQL queries which could be a part of the issue.  One way you can tell is if you trace the network you'll see where the turn around times are causing the issue, if it's from the server side then chances are the generated SQL is not good.  Just a guess, but tracing the line will tell you for sure what's going on.

Comment: Please try to update statistics for the db: `sp_updatestats` and check compatibility level: `SELECT compatibility_level  
FROM sys.databases'

Comment: Are you using Entity Framework? If so you can issue direct SQL Queries to it using EF.  This cuts out any generated queries.

Answer (score 0):

> Any ideas of where this timeout may be coming from?

These are client-side timeouts caused by queries running longer than the SqlCommand.CommandTimeout, which defaults to 30sec.

The recommended upgrade process is to initially leave the databases at their original compatibility level after upgrade to minimize the risk of plan reversion.  Then turn on Query Store to gather a performance baseline before increasing the database compatibility level.  See

[image]
[Change the Database Compatibility Level and use the Query Store](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/install-windows/change-the-database-compatibility-mode-and-use-the-query-store?view=sql-server-ver15)